# Aurora serverles V2 connection

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I've created an Aurora MySQL serverless db cluster in AWS and I want to connect to it from my computer using mySQL Workbench. I've entered the endpoint as well as master user and password, however when I try to connect , it hangs for about one minute and then it says that cannot connect (no further info is given).
Also trying to ping the endpoint, it resolves the name but don't get any answer.
I've read all the documentation from AWS but I really cannot find how to connect. In the vpc security group I've enabled all inbound and outbound traffic on all ports and protocols. The AWS doc says to enable public access in DB settings but I cannot find such an option.

Comment: What you get if you execute these cli from your machine `nc -vz -w 3 "${DB_HOST}" "${DB_PORT}"` or `telnet "${DB_HOST}" "${DB_PORT}"`?

Comment: I'm getting this

$ telnet xxx.cluster-cqnsu2yidmoz.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
Trying 172.xxx.yyy.130...
Connection failed: Connessione scaduta
Trying 172.xxx.www.187...

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-2.limitations.html) Aurora Serverless v2 (preview) or [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.requirements) Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster limitation applicable to your setup? it says "You can't give an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless DB cluster only from within a VPC."

Comment: mmm I did not see that, It's v2 and now I see that you can work with it in the preview env only :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't give an Amazon Aurora Serverless V1 DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless V1 DB cluster only from within a virtual private cloud (VPC), based on the Amazon VPC service. For Aurora Serverless V2 you can make a cluster public. Make sure you have the proper ingress rules set up and enable public access in database configuration. For more information, see Using Amazon Aurora Serverless.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/ .